# If not authenticated redirect and setState in promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import history from './History';


import Home from '../containers/Home';
import Login from '../containers/LogIn';
import CreateUsers from '../containers/CreateUsers';
import Dashboard from '../containers/Dashboard';
import NavBar from './NavBar';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false
        };

        fetch("/api/user")
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                if (res.enabled === 1) {
                    this.setState({
                        isAuthenticated: true
                    });
                    // Redirect the user only if they are on the login page.
                    history.push("/dashboard");
                } else {
                    history.push("/login");
                }
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <div>
                    <NavBar />
                    <Route>
                        <Redirect from="/" to="/login" /> // If not authenticated, how???
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I have two issues, the first is how can I get it to redirect back to the login using Router if the user failed authentication, currently I'm getting the error: `React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child`

The other issue is that it can't see `this` from:

```
.then(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                if (res.enabled === 1) {
                    this.setState({
                        isAuthenticated: true
                    });
...
```

Giving me `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Comment: this.setState state is out of context because this is bound to the function scope not to the scope of the component. You would want to use an arrow function for that reason.

Comment: @Ozan I thought so, what do you mean arrow function?

Answer (score 0):

**1st issue:**
Use state to trigger your `<Redirect/>`. When your fetch finishes we can use the response to update the `isAuthenticated` state so that it triggers a re-render.

```
.then((res) => {
    this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: res.enabled === 1,
    });
});
```

```
render() {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <div>
                {this.state.isAuthenticated && <Redirect from="/" to="/login" />}
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

**2nd issue:**
This doesn't work because you're creating a new function for the response, you can solve this by changing it into an arrow function so that this points to the class OR bind `then` to this.

```
.then((res) => {
    if (res.enabled === 1) {
        this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: true
        });
    }
});

.then(function(res) => {
    if (res.enabled === 1) {
        this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: true
        });
    }
}).bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) use isAuthenticated state to redirect

```
 !this.state.isAuthenticated && (<Route>
     <Redirect from="/" to="/login" /> // If not authenticated, how???
 </Route>)
```

2) use arrow function instead then you will have this from current context binded to the callback

```
.then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res.enabled === 1) {
                this.setState({
                    isAuthenticated: true
                });
                // Redirect the user only if they are on the login page.
                history.push("/dashboard");
            } else {
                history.push("/login");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve your question step by step

1st **`how can I get it to redirect back to the login using Router if the user failed authentication`**

I won't advise for your current approach because everytime you do an authentication (let's say from Facebook, Google), The callback will again reach your **App** Component, Again make a request and this would cause the app to go in endless loop.

Also, Too avoid side effects all the requests should be made in componentDidMount

Personal Suggestion: Use Redux here.

This is how I did client side Authentication using Redux

```
const AuthenticatedRoutes = ({component: Component, ...props})=> {
  return (
   <Route {...props}  render= {(prop) => {

     return (
       props.prop.isAuthenticated ? <Component {...prop} /> :
      <Redirect to={{
       pathname: "/login",
      }}/>
   )}
  }/>
)}

//These roots can;t be seen by users who are authenticated 
const NotAuthenticatedRoutes = ({component: Component, ...props}) => (
  <Route {...props}  render= {(prop) => {

    return (
     !props.prop.isAuthenticated ? <Component {...prop} /> :
     <Redirect to={{
      pathname: "/",
     }}/>
  )}
 }/>
)

class route extends Component {



    render () {

      return(

        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
          <Switch>
            <NotAuthenticatedRoutes exact path ="/login"  component={Login} prop={this.props} />
            <AuthenticatedRoutes exact path  ="/"  component={HomeScreen} prop={this.props} />
        </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isAuthenticated: state.profileInfo.isAuthenticated,
    isLoaded: state.profileInfo.isLoaded,
    googleProfileLoading: state.profileInfo.googleProfileLoading
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, 
  {
    googleProfile
  })(route)
```

Here, If the state of the user in my app isn't set to authenticated, Inside my login Component, I make an API call for login and then set **Redux State**

**2nd:** Copying this from Win answer, Check your function for lexical scoping

```
.then((res) => {
    if (res.enabled === 1) {
        this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: true
        });
    }
});

.then(function(res) => {
    if (res.enabled === 1) {
        this.setState({
            isAuthenticated: true
        });
    }
}).bind(this);
```

**Also, Use ComponentDidMount for Making api calls** to avoid any side effects

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code will work same as it is with minor change. Before making promise,  take this in a variable like below-

let me = this;

and when you promise is completed and you are updating state,  use like below -

me.setState({
                        isAuthenticated: true
                    });

It will work fine.